# How to redirect from servlet to jsp after getting alert?

Tags: jsp, servlets

in my code i want to display alert message, that is coded in the servlet page.
    and then i want to redirect to jsp. i got alert message. but it doesn't redirect. Please check my code?

```
catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
            String someMessage = "Vehicle already Assigned";            
            out.println("<html><head>");
            out.println("<script type='text/javascript'>");
            out.println("alert(" + "'" + someMessage + "'" + ");</script>");
            out.println("</head><body></body></html>");
    }
```

Where i put this line

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("VehicleSchedule.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Can't do two things (forwarding a request and returning a response) at once.

Comment: Ohhhh i see... is there any other option to redirect with alert message?
 if u know pls share with me dear **Kohei TAMURA**

Comment: If you want to forward a request to JSP with the error message, you should write `request.setAttribute("errorMessage", someMessage);` in your servlet and `<%=request.getAttribute("errorMessage")%>` in VehicleSchedule.jsp

Comment: yes sure. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this but i am not really recomend!

```
out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
            out.println("alert('YOUR MESSAGE');");
            out.println("window.location.href = \"YourPage.jsp\";");
            out.println("</script>");
```

This is a tricky and easy way to do this! But you can do this with `session` also if you want.

Comment: ohhhhh Thanks dear **Fotis Grigorakis**

Comment: If my answer helped you, you can accept it and up vote it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use javascript code along with your alert message, However it will redirect your request and will not dispatch it with any data.

```
 out.println("<script type='text/javascript'>");
 out.println("alert(" + "'" + someMessage + "'" + ");</script>");
 **out.println("window.location.href = 'myPage.jsp';");**
```

So if you want to pass any data along with request object, you will need to append it in URL or add it in Session object.

```
out.println("window.location.href = 'myPage.jsp?var1=value1';");

 or 

session.setAttribute("var1","val1");
```